# LayoutError at /invoice/ Flowable <PmlTable@0x1D09C899130 7 rows x 5 cols(tallest row 841)> with cell(0,0)

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to print invoice in PDF format in Django I used **xhtml2pdf** to convert HTML doc. to PDF but when I try to run my code it gives me this error :

> *`LayoutError at /invoice/ Flowable <PmlTable@0x1D09C899130 7 rows x 5 cols(tallest row 841)> with cell(0,0) containing '<PmlKeepInFrame at 0x1d09b77d670> size=x'(538.5826771653543 x 5893.228346456693), tallest cell 841.9 points,  too large on page 2 in frame 'body'(538.5826771653543 x 785.19685039370`*

this is in my **views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from booking.utils import render_to_pdf
from django.template.loader import get_template

class GeneratePDF(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        template = get_template('invoice.html')
        context = {
            "invoice_id": 1234,
            "customer_name": "John Cooper",
            "amount": 1399.99,
            "today": "Today",
        }
        html = template.render(context)
        pdf = render_to_pdf('invoice.html', context)
        if pdf:
            response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
            filename = "Invoice_%s.pdf" %("12341231")
            content = "inline; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            download = request.GET.get("download")
            if download:
                content = "attachment; filename='%s'" %(filename)
            response['Content-Disposition'] = content
            return response
        return HttpResponse("Not found")
```

and this is my **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from booking.views import GeneratePDF

app_name = 'booking'

urlpatterns = [
  path('invoice/', GeneratePDF.as_view(), name ="invoice"),
]
```

Comment: Could you please include `invoice.html` in the question so that users can attempt to recreate the issue thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer
**xhtml2pdf** is not able to split table cells that are larger than the available space. 
To work around it you may define what should happen in this case. 
The `-pdf-keep-in-frame-mode` can be one of: `“error”, “overflow”, “shrink”, “truncate”` where `“shrink”` is the default value.

```
table {    -pdf-keep-in-frame-mode: shrink;}
```

[documentation link](https://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#long-cells)